# I am getting this error as shown in body, while building a apk file in ubuntu, please help me to solve this error

Tags: java, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, flutter-layout, java-home

chinmay@chinmay-Latitude-E6420:~/MyFiles/FlutterExercise/again$ flutter build apk

Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory:  "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15-0.2"

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      138ms
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
chinmay@chinmay-Latitude-E6420:~/MyFiles/FlutterExercise/again$

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with your environment configuration. Open Command Palette and choose **Java: Configure Java Runtime**.

**Java Tooling Runtime --> Java Language Server**, this option is equal to the setting `"java.home"`. Java extension automatically detects the compatible jdk on local machine and lists the path here for user to choose. Make sure you've set [JAVA_HOME](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/) properly on your local machine.

[image]

Don't forget to **reload window** to make the change effective.